# Is "Crypto Core" a micro-controller (or FPGA) which is able to do Proof-of-Work completely?

Tags: pow, internet-of-things, proof-of-work, energy-consumption

Is "**[Crypto Core](https://ecosystem.iota.org/projects/iota-crypto-core-fpga)**" a micro-controller (or FPGA) which is able to do Proof-of-Work completely ?

As I heard that micro-controllers are **not** able to perform **Proof-of-Work**, because of power and energy limitations.

Answer (score 1):

The Crypto Core is a FPGA system which consists of Cortex M1 soft-cpu and specialized logic for accelerating algorithms like hashing (and also PoW) or type-conversions.

So, it's both - microcontroller in an FPGA and it can do PoW very fast :)

Comment: Thank you, Could please also put here a link containing a picture of hardware of **Crypto Core** along with its hardware specifications (including its dimension as well)? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Proof-of-Work was implemented in VHDL between 26th April '18 and 26th Aug '18 and became the PiDiver: https://github.com/shufps/iota_vhdl_pow (Source: https://gitlab.com/iccfpga/iccfpga-core/wikis/home)

Micro-controllers and PoW are not the best combination, one solution to it is [Azimuth](https://blog.iota.org/eli9-azimuth-previously-known-as-nb-pow-f36156d378e4)